# App launch from widget if app is not running

Tags: android, widget

I create a home screen widget whenever my app launches. But when I kill the app, and click on my widget, I need to launch the app. When the app is running in background or foreground, I must be able to do actions from the widget. My code for pending intent is -

```
public static PendingIntent buildButtonPendingIntent(Context context) {
        ++MyWidgetReceiver.clickCount;
        // initiate widget update request
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        //App launch if app is not running
        Intent iSetting = new Intent(context, App.class);
        PendingIntent piSetting = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, iSetting, 0);

    }
```

How do I do this for app killed and app launching from widget. My code is sort of incomplete.